# Can you submit a paper to a journal that contains a paper already accepted?

Tags: publications, journals

I have just got a short paper (about 3,500 words) accepted by a top journal and it is currently being copy-edited. Meanwhile I have completed a paper (about 12,000 words) with deeper research that contains the short paper as a whole. The new paper reorganizes and expands on the short paper in a way that improves on the accuracy, although it takes much of the short paper contents verbatim. Then it adds an entirely new section. Is it inappropriate to submit this to a journal?

Comment: I am no sure what "reorganizes and expands..in a way that improves the accuracy" means in this case. However, nothing from an accepted paper should be used verbatim in a new paper. You must rewrite all these sections and cite the short paper.

Answer (score 10):

It is quite common, to publish a short letter-like paper to a high-impact journal first and then follow it up with a more detailed longer paper expanding on the first one.

However, containing the first paper as a subset is (self-)plagiarism, not original, and not acceptable. You must write the second paper independently, though some similarity of the text is okay, in particular if you state explicitly which passage has already been presented in that earlier paper and are only included for completeness.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. By "write the second paper independently" do you mean not to use the same expressions verbatim but rephrase all of them? About citing, I cannot cite the shorter paper in the submission because that would reveal my identity as the author and break the anonymity requirement.

Comment: Are you sure regarding the anonymity requirement? Whose requirement is that? Not citing the short paper is unacceptable, as it would pretend the new submission is entirely original, i.e. this is plagiarism. You should clarify with whoever you think forbids quoting that paper how to proceed.